# how can i use openai's gpt 3 to find alternate spellings of bad words?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

so, i am making an auto mod discord bot that finds alternate spellings of bad words. i tried using regex to find them but found many many false positives. so i thought about using openai's gpt-3 to do so, as i saw a screenshot of someone using it for what appears to be finding alternate spellings.

the screenshot:

[image: the screenshot:]

unfortunately, i don't know how exactly they made gpt-3 do this, and how something like this can be used in an application like a discord bot.

can someone please tell me how you can use gpt-3 to find alternate spellings of words?

any help would be appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking for prompt/settings. However, based on my experience (3-4 months) I would use a few-shot approach prompt such this one:

```
Check spelling and return the corrected word:
Word: nawty
Returns: naughty
Word: rigt
Returns: right
Word: stakoverflow
Returns:
```

I guess that a high temperature and no penalties will do a good job. Also, keep trying different engines and see how it behaves. Curie-instruct-beta should do it.

Comment: First, you need access to openai gpt-3 api: https://beta.openai.com/
Documentation: https://beta.openai.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Currently (April 2023) you can do this using the openAI API.
Here is an [example](https://platform.openai.com/examples/default-grammar) from API documentation:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
-d '{
"model": "text-davinci-003",
"prompt": "Correct this to standard English:\n\nShe no went to the market.",
"temperature": 0,
"max_tokens": 60,
"top_p": 1.0,
"frequency_penalty": 0.0,
"presence_penalty": 0.0
}'
```